# Нужна ли запятая перед "да"?

Tags: пунктуация

В "Большом словаре русских пословиц" в пословице "Не корми калачом, да не бей в спину кирпичом" стоит запятая. Но разве здесь "да" не в значении "и"?

Answer (score 5):

Здесь **нужна** запятая, так как **ДА употреблено в значении НО** (или ТОЛЬКО). Значение пословицы: отказ от какого-то блага в обмен на отсутствие зла. Ср.: *Не корми калачом, ТОЛЬКО не бей в спину кирпичом.*

Answer (score 1):

Самый близкий, как мне кажется, по значению текст: Лучше не корми калачом, но (=да) только не бей в спину кирпичом.